# str() method adds whitespace characters

Tags: python, regex, string, web-crawler, urllib

How do you prevent python from adding the whitespace characters when calling str()? I have a screen scraper/web crawler that uses urllib.request. I'm calling str() on my content.
Here is the code I have.

```
req = urllib.request.Request(national_url, headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"})
con = urllib.request.urlopen( req )

#grab html
html = con.read()
my_str = str(html)
```

the problem is i use regex to parse this html for some patterns, and str adds all the whitespace characters like \n and \t.

My question is how do I prevent the str() function from adding these additional characters literals.

EDIT

I was using urllib2 before in a python 2.7 script I wrote. I brought it over to a new pc but started using python 3.6 on this pc. These regular expressions no longer worked. I was getting an error when I passed con.read() to this function. I wrapped the con.read() in a call to str() as shown above, and I noticed in 3.6, with the con.read() function added a whole bunch of \t's and 
n's. My question is how do I either make my expressions work, or prohibit all of the "charater literals" otherwise known as '\t\n' (I will admit that I'm probably using the wrong term for those characters).

This was working in Python 2.7. I switched to python 3.6.

```
def parse_html_doc(str='', poke_id = 0):
    if len(str) > 0:

        poke = MyClass()
        poke.dex_num = re.search('\d+(?=<\/strong>)', str).group(0)
        poke.name = re.search('[A-Za-z]+(?=<\/h1>)', str).group(0)
        poke.hp = re.search('\d+', re.search('<th>HP<\/th>\s+<td class="num">\d+<\/td>', str).group(0)).group(0)
        poke.atk = re.search('\d+', re.search('<th>Attack<\/th>\s+<td class="num">\d+<\/td>', str).group(0)).group(0)
        poke.bdef = re.search('\d+', re.search('<th>Defense<\/th>\s+<td class="num">\d+<\/td>', str).group(0)).group(0)
        poke.spatk = re.search('\d+', re.search('<th>Sp\. Atk<\/th>\s+<td class="num">\d+<\/td>', str).group(0)).group(0)
        poke.spatk = re.search('\d+', re.search('<th>Sp\. Def<\/th>\s+<td class="num">\d+<\/td>', str).group(0)).group(0)
        poke.spd = re.search('\d+', re.search('<th>Speed<\/th>\s+<td class="num">\d+<\/td>', str).group(0)).group(0)
        poke.des = re.search('<p>.*<\/p>', str).group(0).replace('"', '""')
        poke.id = poke_id
        return poke
```

Comment: Please define "Adding these additional character literals". Do you mean that they are not there before you call str and then they appear after? Or do you mean you do not like they way they are displayed?  Can you give use example output?

Comment: "str adds all the whitespace characters like \n and \t" - no it doesn't. "the problem is i use regex to parse this html for some patterns" - yes, that is certainly a problem. Don't use regexes to parse HTML. Use a real parser, like BeautifulSoup.

Comment: `str()` doesn't add this chars - they exist all the time - and this is why we use parsers like `lxml` or `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: you dont see line breaks in browser because html content type doesnt render line break character, but that does not mean source html dont have line breaks. You just need to use re.DOTALL flag on regex

Comment: updated the original post with more information.

Comment: _"How do you prevent python from adding the whitespace characters when calling str()"_ - it is a certainty that `str` doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

`str()` doesn't create those characters, they were already there.

If you want to remove `\n` and `whitespace` at the beginning and the end of a string, then you can just use

```
s = '\n     bla 123\n 1235\n ...\n'
result = s.strip()
print(result)

> 'bla 123\n 1235\n ...'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to do this:

```
eq = urllib.request.Request(national_url, headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"})
con = urllib.request.urlopen( req )

#grab html
html = con.read()
my_str = str(html.replace("\n", "")
my_str = my_str.replace("\t", "")
```

This should remove all the white space characters from your string.

Comment: This didn't work for me, as maketrans does not exist in the string module.

Comment: seems as if I was wrong. `string.maketrans` was deprecated. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Still getting an error.     my_str = str(html.translate(str.maketrans("\n\t\r", "")))
ValueError: the first two maketrans arguments must have equal length

Comment: hmmmm. I haven't used maketrans a lot as such I wasn't aware of this. I'll find another way then update the answer.

Comment: the replace still didn't seem to do the trick either. This is what I wrote to copy you, and all the \t and \n are still there.                                       html = con.read()
my_str = str(html).replace("\n", "")
my_str = my_str.replace("\t", "")